# Wordpress SQL Delete Custom Post Types and Meta

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have the following SQL query which is able to fetch and delete all of the posts of a custom post type that is older than X days.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_type` = ‘clothing’
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 2

DELETE * FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_type` = ‘clothing’
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 2
```

However from what I've read online, it seems that the code above doesn't really delete the posts's meta information, so I'll still have a bunch of left over data.

My question is, how can I modify this code so that all of the related meta information is also removed from the deleted posts?

Thanks

Comment: I used Mac OS's Text Editor with Plain Text mode

Comment: Well in that case uncheck "Smart Quotes" under Edit > Substitutions > Smart Quotes - or wherever it is these days

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can delete the data by joining the tables. In WP `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` are related with `post_id` in the `wp_postmeta` table. Using the query below it will delete from both tables. However there are other options as well i.e you can fire a trigger after delete on `wp_posts` to delete the data from the related table or a foreign key constraint with on delete cascade

```
delete
p,pm
from wp_posts p
join wp_postmeta pm on pm.post_id = p.id
where p.post_type = 'clothing'
and DATEDIFF(NOW(), p.post_date) > 2
```

Comment: I tried this query but for some reason PHPMyAdmin told me that the p,pm results in an error. I replaced it with * and that worked. Would this also be correct in this case?

Comment: Error ? p and pm are just the alias names and should not give error here is a demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/507a38

Comment: Sorry the error was caused because I replaced the delete with select . This works perfectly fine  :)

Comment: A little late, but to anyone else reading this - make sure to use LEFT JOIN on wp_postmeta; otherwise, any posts that don't currently have meta data associated with them will remain in the database.

Comment: Don't forget to use `$wpdb->prefix` instead of `wp_` for case when WP uses non-default database prefix.